# how to make an iterator class a member of a container class c++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, namespaces, initialization

I have an container class (myvector) and an iterator class (const_myiterator)

I want to initialize an iterator like this

```
auto myit = myvector<int>::const_myiterator{myvec.cbegin()};
```

As I can do with std::vector class

```
auto it = std::vector<int>::const_iterator{vec.cbegin()};
```

But I don't know how to implement this

Comment: Are you familiar with nested nested classes and/or type aliases? If that is the case what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the problems you have? How to create an iterator class in general? How to create a `const_iterator` class? How to initialize the iterator class? How to define a class inside a class?

Comment: You could also do `auto it = vec.cbegin();`

Comment: @Some programmer dude The question was how to define a template class inside a class without its realization

Comment: You define classes inside classes just like you define *any* class. Template or not doesn't matter. With that said, the iterator class doesn't have to be a template, if defined inside a template then it already have access to the surrounding templates arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am very sorry for I asked this question without trying to solve the problem myself.
Thanks all who said me about a nested classes. I heard about them before but never used yet
and therefore didn't remember them.
The answer was given in comments by @Some programmer dude
"You define classes inside classes just like you define any class. Template or not doesn't matter. With that said, the iterator class doesn't have to be a template, if defined inside a template then it already have access to the surrounding templates arguments."
Thank you very much!